# Как получить значения из таблицы БД в Builder C++?

Tags: c++builder, база-данных, c++

Имеется БД Access, подключенная к Builder C++ через ADOConnection, ADOTable и DataSource.
Таблица такого вида:

```
Код | Название | R | G | B |
---- ---------- --- --- --- 
  1 | Lime     |164|196| 0 |
---- ---------- --- --- ---
  2 | Green    | 96|169| 23|
            ...
```

Создан компонент DBLookupComboBox, который выводит список поля "Название", KeyField="Код". Если выбран, к примеру, Green, то как получить значения 96,169,23 из таблицы? Они необходимы для выполнения этой команды:

`Form1->Color = RGB (96, 169, 23);`

Answer (score 1):

По-моему лучше использовать ADOQuery:

```
sql = "select R, G, B from colors where id=1";
query->SQL->Text = sql;
query->Active = true;
int r = query->FieldByName["R"]->AsIngeger;
int g = query->FieldByName["G"]->AsIngeger;
int b = query->FieldByName["B"]->AsIngeger;
```

Comment: Появилась проблема: DBLookupComboBox выводит список , выбираешь что-нибудь - цвет формы (по умолчанию зеленый) всегда меняется на черный (последняя запись в БД), а список становится пустым.
Полное описание моих действий:
1. Помещаем на форму TADOConnection, TADOQuery и TDataSourse.
2. 2xЛКМ по ADOConnection1 -> Use Connection String -> Build... -> Microsoft Jet 4.0OLE DB Provider -> Далее >> -> Указываем путь к БД (в формате *mdb) -> Проверить соединение -> ОК -> ОК. Свойство LoginPrompt – устанавливаем в False (чтобы не требовал пароль к БД). Свойство Connection устанавливаем в True.

Comment: 4. Переходим к ADOQuery1. Свойство Connection выбираем ADOConnection1. В свойстве SQL пишем SELECT * FROM Цвета; Цвета - название таблицы.
4. Переходим к TDataSource1. Свойство DataSet выбираем ADOQuery1.
5. Переходим к ADOQuery1. Свойство Active переводим в true.
6. Переходим к DBLookupComboBox1. Свойство ListSource=DataSource1, ListField=Название (поле, которое нужно выводить в списке), KeyField=Код (ключевое поле).

Comment: void __fastcall TForm1::DBLookupComboBox1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
ADOQuery1->Close();
    ADOQuery1->SQL->Clear();
    ADOQuery1->SQL->Text = "SELECT * FROM Цвета WHERE Название = '"+DBLookupComboBox1->Text+"';";
    ADOQuery1->Active = true; // Надо следить, ибо почему-то постоянно в свойствах сбрасывается, тогда и эта строчка не помогает,приходится ручками в свойствах ставить 
    ADOQuery1->Open();
    int r = ADOQuery1->FieldByName("R")->AsInteger;
    int g = ADOQuery1->FieldByName("G")->AsInteger;
    int b = ADOQuery1->FieldByName("B")->AsInteger;
    Form1->Color = RGB (r,g,b);
}

Comment: Все оказалось проще простого:

void __fastcall TForm1::DBLookupComboBox1Click(TObject *Sender)

{

int r = ADOQuery1->FieldByName("R")->AsInteger;

int g = ADOQuery1->FieldByName("G")->AsInteger;

int b = ADOQuery1->FieldByName("B")->AsInteger;

Form1->Color = RGB (r,g,b);

}